# Unable to write a file in classic asp using IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, asp-classic, permissions

I am using Windows 2003 and have an IIS website.

I created a file called `test.asp` in the `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` directory with the following contents:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is the text in the text file:</p>
    <%
    Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set f = fs.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath("testread.txt"), true)
    Response.Write("This Worked!")
    f.Close

    Set f = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    %>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I view the page, I get the generic "Page cannot be displayed" which makes me think that there is an error in my script.  I have tracked it down to the `CreateTextFile` function, it somehow fails.

**My First question:**

Is there anyway to debug this?  I don't know how to view errors with this page, I always just get the *"Page cannot be displayed"*.

**Second question:**

I don't know if there might be some sort of permissions issue?  I tried setting the permissions of the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` key in registry to full control for `EVERYONE`.

I don't know what else could be preventing me from writing a file?  I have verified that I can read a file with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Internet Explorer make sure you have the following setting **unchecked**:

`Tools -> Options -> Advance Tab -> Show Friendly HTTP error messages`

The next thing to check is that the anonymous account for the site has write access to the `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder.

*In IIS6, to find the site's anonymous account:*

Open IIS MMC by clicking -

```
Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools  
                           -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
```

Browse and select the `Default Web Site` then right click and select `Properties`. On the tabbed dialogue select the *Directory Security* tab.

Click the `Edit` button in the *Authentication and access control* panel. Note the value in the `User name` field (whatever you do don't alter this). Click the `Cancel` button twice to dismiss these dialogues.

In explorer right click and open the properties of `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`. Select the *Security* tab and make sure that the anonymous account noted above is added and has at the very least `Modify` permissions.